# import the all xml attribute value with click method

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i have Something this type of xml with huge of data:-

```
<root>
      <child1 id="4331" value="twenty-twenty">
                 <child2 id="4332" value="India">
                            <child4 id="4334" value="Mumbai Indian"></chlild4>
                            <child5 id="4335" value="Rajshthan Royal"></child5>
                 </child2>
                 <child3 id="4333" value="Pakishtan">
                             <child6 id="4336" value="Arngabad"></child6>
                             <child7 id="4337" value="Punjab"></child7>
                 </child3>
      </child1>
</root>
```

i tried this

```
 <html>                                                                  
 <head>                                                                  
 <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>          
 <script type="text/javascript">                                         
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $("button").click(function() {
   });
 });  
 $(function() {
$.ajax({
             type: "GET",
             url: "atry.xml",
             dataType: "xml",
             success: function(xml) { 
             data = xml;
             $(xml).find('*').each(function(){
    console.log($(this).attr('id'));
    console.log($(this).attr('value'));
    });//close $.each(
    }
 }); //close click(
});
 </script>                                                               
 </head>                                                                 
 <body>                                                                  
   <!-- we will add our HTML content here --> 
 <button>Link</button>   
 </body>                                                                 
 </html>
```

i am try this but no output display...

import the all child attribute using jquery with click event...

thanks

Comment: Did you tried something?

Comment: @deepa you should google it first before asking

Comment: @ArunC.B no i dont know any thing about this

Comment: SO is not meant for prblms whose solution you can get through google's 'i'am feeling lucky' .

Comment: @muthu i am add my code above please check now

Comment: You should use these value in your own way for your purpose, I just only log them.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code with jquery:

```
var xml  = '<root><child1 id="4331" value="twenty-twenty"><child2 id="4332" value="India"><child4 id="4334" value="Mumbai Indian"></chlild4><child5 id="4335" value="Rajshthan Royal"></child5></child2><child3 id="4333" value="Pakishtan"><child6 id="4336" value="Arngabad"></child6><child7 id="4337" value="Punjab"></child7></child3></child1></root>';

var $root = $(xml);
$root.find('*').each(function(){
    console.log($(this).attr('id'));
    console.log($(this).attr('value'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
     $.ajax({
             type: "GET",
             url: "atry.xml",
             dataType: "xml",
             success: function(xml) { 
             data = xml;
             $(xml).find('*').each(function(){
    console.log($(this).attr('id'));
    console.log($(this).attr('value'));
    });//close $.each
    }
 });  //cloase ajax 

  }); //close button click

}); //close ready
```